# Selecionando todos os elementos da página?

Tags: javascript, grid, elementos

Estava pensando a respeito do `Grid-CSS`, li em alguns sites sobre os `frameworks` que existem para ele, e que em geral são muito ruins, pois limitam a capacidade da tecnologia, então pensei, por que ninguém faz um `framework`, onde o `javascript` verifica todos os elementos, um a um, e se eles possuirem `data-attributes` referentes à utilização do sistema de `grid`, aplicar determinadas regras para esses elementos de acordo com os valores adicionados pelo desenvolvedor (em geral, as classes determinam as propriedades utilizadas, mas isso limitaria o número de colunas, linhas, onde cada coisa começa ou termina e por aí vai, já, se ele apenas atribuir os valores a essas propriedades, o único limite seria colocado pelo próprio desenvolvedor)? (ex: `<span data-grid-column-spacing="2/6">...</span>`).

Para isso, pensei em, criar funções separadas que selecionam os `data-attributes` de acordo com o que for usado, é uma possibilidade, mas pensei, por que não selecionar todos os elementos de uma vez, e então verificar e adicionar os estilos em cada um ?

- Sendo assim, a minha dúvida é, como posso selecionar todos os elementos de uma vez, independentemente do nome do elemento, ou em qual lugar da página ele está?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para selecionar todos os elementos de uma página HTML, utilize o querySelectorAll, através de seletores CSS ou getElementsByTagName, através do simbolo `*` para selecionar todos os nodes. Veja nas implementações abaixo:

**[getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)**

```
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

**[querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)**

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('*');
```